# how can we toggle class between 2 buttons in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I achieve like a toggle button effect, when BTN1 is clicked add class active to it and when BTN2 is clicked add active class to it and remove the active class from BTN1..like so,

From my code, I have achieved the add/remove class on the same button click only,

```
<button (click)="callAPI1()" [ngClass]="clicked1 ? 'active' : ''">BTN1</button>
<button (click)="callAPI2()" [ngClass]="clicked2 ? 'active' : ''">BTN1</button>
```

in my ts

```
clicked1:boolean = false;
clicked2:boolean = false;

callAPI1(){
   this.clicked1 = !this.clicked1;
   console.log('Api 1 called')
}

callAPI2(){
   this.clicked2 = !this.clicked2;
   console.log('Api2 called')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one flag.

See the code below

Controller:

```
isActive: boolean = null;
```

Template

```
<button (click)="isActive = true" [class.active]="isActive">BTN1</button>
<button (click)="isActive = false" [class.active]="!isActive">BTN1</button>
```

This way it wont show Button 2 active on two times click of Button 1

Comment: @aslamkhursheed can you accept my answer so it helps to others?